# Using @Configuration to access configs in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a custom deserializer class that needs to read in some custom configurations in my Spring Boot application. My class looks somewhat like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class ItemDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 
 
    @Value("${config.name}")
    private String nameConfig;

    public ItemDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 
 
    public ItemDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }
 
    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        
        //read in item name based on configuration value
        String itemName = node.get(nameConfig).asText();
 
        return new Item(itemName);
    }
}
```

and I am invoking it on the Item class like so:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemDeserializer.class)
public class Item {
      private String itemName;

      //getters and setters
}
```

The `nameConfig` field never gets set with the appropriate configuration value. Adding the @Configuration works in other parts of my app, but those classes include @Bean annotations and other things that I suspect are necessary. How can I annotate this class to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "works in other parts of my app". Could you please clarify the issue you are facing?

Comment: @M.Mas. I have expanded my question a little. When I say that it works in other parts of my app, I am saying that I successfully get configurations the same way in other parts of my app as I am in this class... annotating it with Configuration and getting the value with Value.

Comment: You are saying that by adding @Configuration, the problem is solved. Can you please add the code or the use case in which you are getting a problem? thanks

Comment: @M.Mas. the above code is the problem. It does not work. The value of nameConfig is always null even though it is set in my configuration file.

Comment: you said "The value of nameConfig is always null even though it is set in my configuration file".... If you print the environment  of the app e.g.,  loalhost:8080/actuator/env , are you seeing the value of "config.name" ? is it in yur config-props file..

Comment: @zee, yep I can see it. I am still new to Spring, is there some edge case I am running into because I am using this within a custom deserializer class?

Comment: The best way to go about debugging this is to put break pints and run the app in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` if you are using Spring Framework 2.5+.

```
public class ItemDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 
 
    @Value("${config.name}")
    private String nameConfig;

    public ItemDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 
 
    public ItemDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
     super(vc);        
     SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);    
        
    }
 
    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        
        //read in item name based on configuration value
        String itemName = node.get(nameConfig).asText();
 
        return new Item(itemName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually using an older version of Spring, but I'll probably upgrade so I can leverage this feature. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.

You will not be able to use it this way, you need another strategy. I recommend give this link a read: https://www.baeldung.com/java-properties